# Concise Way To Specify The Space Of All Python Programs Under A Certain Size And Running Time?

Tags: computability, enumeration

Given the grammar of the Python language, is there a concise way to specify the space of all possible (and correct) Python programs?

To avoid the underlying halting problem, the specification would include a user-definable maximum program size and running time. This concise specification could then be fed to another program, a search/optimization algorithm to be precise, as the domain to operate in. And yes, I'm aware of how intractable such a space would be.

I don't know much about computer science or language theory, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't _avoid_ the halting problem this way, you _add it_ to what your enumerator has to solve. Since even separating $\Theta(n^2)$ from $\Theta(n^3)$ is undecidable in general ([proof](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/are-runtime-bounds-in-p-decidable-answer-no/5011#5011)), you won't get anywhere by that. Similiarly, for any useful notion of "correctness" deciding whether a program is correct is likely to be undecidable as well. (Keep in mind that enumerating _all_ programs is trivial.)

Comment: The idea is not useful in practice because there are exponentially many programs and searching through them naively is a fruitless effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can't determine the running time of a generic program automatically, this is an [undecidable problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) similar to the Halting problem.

Maybe you can try to enumerate a very well defined subset of the possible codes up to certain size. But in order to be useful for an search/optimization algorithm (other than random search), this subset needs to be equipped with some sort of vicinity function. Moreover, this vicinity function should allow you to explore genuinely different programs. Preferably this function should form a connected space among all plausible programs in this subset, and have a short diameter so optimizer can succeed on the search. All that said, is pretty clear that the problem is far from being easy.

I read recently a very interesting post about applying genetic algorithm to produce brainfuck code to solve specific simple tasks. You can read [it here](http://www.primaryobjects.com/2013/01/27/using-artificial-intelligence-to-write-self-modifying-improving-programs/). The post is from 2013, but there is no particular breakthrough in this area that I'm aware. This field is known as program-synthesis and there are a lot of teams working on it, most recently they are trying to use classic combinatorial algorithms boosted with deep learning to prune the search space.

Comment: You can't determine the running time of a generic program automatically, but it is trivial to determine if a generic program runs under a given time bound: just time it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question once and thought that the [K Framework](https://kframework.org/) would be a good place to start (I didn't pursue it).

From https://experts.illinois.edu/en/publications/specifying-languages-and-verifying-programs-with-k:

> The K framework is designed to allow implementing a variety of generic
> tools that can be used with any language defined in K, such as
> parsers, interpreters, symbolic execution engines, semantic debuggers,
> test-case generators, state-space explorers, model checkers, and even
> deductive program verifiers.

There is a Python implementation:

https://github.com/kframework/python-semantics